# How to prevent high cpu usage by xorg when using multiple keyboards the same time

Tags: keyboard, xfce, performance

I am encountering weird problem when using external usb keyboard connected to my laptop.
When I am doing keypresses both on usb keyboard and the one from laptop (i.e. keep pressing ctrl on the first one and shift on second one) system load goes heavily up and CPU is on 90%. This seems XFCE specific :(

What I have tried so far:

- Different usb keyboards (same effect)
- Two usb keyboads and not using generic laptop keyboard (same effect)
- Different system: Ubuntu 12 (problem does not exists there)
- Console (alt+ctrl+F1) and top (problem does not exists)
- Typing only on one keyboard at a time (no problem)
- Other window managers (KDE / Fluxbox) works fine

Top shows that xorg server is getting high cpu usage. Nothing new in dmesg and syslog during problem.

I am using Slackware 14.2 and XFCE. My laptop is IBM T60.
UPDATE: This seems to be XFCE specific. Still investigating problem. There is no problem on KDE / Fluxbox.

What should be changed or which options should be enabled to resolve this issue.

Comment: Ubuntu 12? Seriously, a distribution from 5 YEARS AGO you are using to probe issues?  `Xorg.0.log` say something to you?

Comment: @nwildner There is nothing revelant in Xorg.log to this problem, which I am aware of. If I knew where to start with, I would not ask such question. Also point with Ubuntu is, that in some point of time there possibly existed configuration (kernel / udev / xorg / other thing) which was not producing such problem.